# An Explanation of MySqlBulkLoader

Tags: c#, mysql

Can you tell me what `MySqlBulkLoader` is for, where and how to use it?

Some examples would also be appreciated, please..

Comment: Read following docs(with example):: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html

Answer (score 5):

`MySQLBulkLoader` is a class in the MySQL Connector/Net class that wraps the MySQL statement `LOAD DATA INFILE`. This gives MySQL Connector/Net the ability to load a data file from a local or remote host to the server. [[MySQLBulkLoader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html)]

The example how to use the `MySQLBulkLoader` is also presented [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html)

**To be clear:**
The `MySQLBulkLoader` is not similar to `SQLBulkCopy`. `SQLBulkCopy` also called `Bulk insert` reads data from `DataTable` and `MySQLBulkLoader` also called `LOAD DATA INFILE` reads from a file. If you have a list of data to insert in you database, it is possible to prepare and insert data inside you database directly with `SQLBulkCopy`; where with the `MySQLBulkoader` you will need to genereate a file from your data before running the command.

There are no counterpart of `SQLBulkCopy` inside MySQL Connector/Net at the time writting; however, the `MySQL DB` support `Bulk insert`, so you can run the corresponding command in a `MySQLCommand` like presented [Here](http://jishnutkl.wordpress.com/tag/mysql-bulk-insert-from-c-net/).

Answer (score 4):

`MySqlBulkLoader` is a class provided by the [MySql .net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

It provides an interface to MySql that is similar in concept to the [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class / BCP for Sql Server. Basically, it allows you to load data into MySql in bulk. A decent looking example can be found at [dragthor.wordpress.com](http://dragthor.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/mysql-connector-net-mysqlbulkloader-example/) and there's also an example in the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html).

Comment: you answer is actually totally **false**. It is not similar to `sqlbulkcopy` at all. `MySqlBulkLoader` is for loading file data. And  `sqlbulkcopy` is for loading `system.data.datatable` and related structures