# Bulk copy a DataTable into MySQL (similar to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy)

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am migrating my program from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL. Everything works well except one issue with bulk copy.

In the solution with MS SQL the code looks like this:

```
connection.Open();
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "testTable";
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(rawData);
```

Now I try to do something similar for MySQL. Because I think there would be bad performance I don't want to write the DataTable to a CSV file and do the insert from there with the `MySqlBulkLoader` class.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a C# program read a text file into memory and then pass that object to a method that requires a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308208/can-a-c-sharp-program-read-a-text-file-into-memory-and-then-pass-that-object-to)

Comment: Also another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23537155/2144390). Regarding performance, have you done any tests to see if dumping the data to disk and then using `MySqlBulkLoader` will really be a problem, or will actually be worse than some other "roll your own" solution that does not use a temporary file?

Comment: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions
has this feature

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Because I think there would be bad performance I don't want to write the DataTable to a CSV file and do the insert from there with the MySqlBulkLoader class.

Don't rule out a possible solution based on unfounded assumptions. I just tested the insertion of 100,000 rows from a `System.Data.DataTable` into a MySQL table using a standard `MySqlDataAdapter#Update()` inside a `Transaction`. It consistently took about 30 seconds to run:

```cs
using (MySqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM testtable";
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.UpdateBatchSize = 1000;
            using (MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da))
            {
                da.Update(rawData);
                tran.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I tried a couple of different values for `UpdateBatchSize` but they didn't seem to have a significant impact on the elapsed time.)

By contrast, the following code using `MySqlBulkLoader` took only 5 or 6 seconds to run ...

```cs
string tempCsvFileSpec = @"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\dump.csv";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempCsvFileSpec))
{
    Rfc4180Writer.WriteDataTable(rawData, writer, false);
}
var msbl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
msbl.TableName = "testtable";
msbl.FileName = tempCsvFileSpec;
msbl.FieldTerminator = ",";
msbl.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
msbl.Load();
System.IO.File.Delete(tempCsvFileSpec);
```

... including the time to dump the 100,000 rows from the DataTable to a temporary CSV file (using code similar to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665519/Writing-a-DataTable-to-a-CSV-file)), bulk-loading from that file, and deleting the file afterwards.

Comment: Thank you verry much. I found that out by myself after your second comment :-)

Comment: The code using MySqlBulkLoader doen't work for me, unless I add msbl.LineTerminator = "\r\n"

Answer (score 6):

Similar to SqlBulkCopy, we have MySqlBulkCopy for Mysql.
here is the example how to use it.

```
public async Task<bool> MySqlBulCopyAsync(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        try
        {
            bool result = true;
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection(_connString + ";AllowLoadLocalInfile=True"))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "yourtable";
                // the column mapping is required if you have a identity column in the table
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.AddRange(GetMySqlColumnMapping(dataTable));
                await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    private List<MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping> GetMySqlColumnMapping(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        List<MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping> colMappings = new List<MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            colMappings.Add(new MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(i, col.ColumnName));
            i++;
        }
        return colMappings;
    }
```

You can ignore the column mapping if you don't have any identity column in your table.
If you have identity column then you have to use the column mapping otherwise it won't insert any records in the table
It will just give message like "x rows were copied but only 0 rows were inserted".

This class i available in the below library
Assembly MySqlConnector, Version=1.0.0.0

Answer (score 5):

Using any of BulkOperation NuGet-package, you can easily have this done.

Here is an example using the package from  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.BulkOperations/2.14.3/

```
MySqlConnection conn = DbConnection.OpenConnection();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("testtable");
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM testtable", conn);
MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(dt);
```

instead of using

```
......
da.UpdateBatchSize = 1000;
......
da.Update(dt)
```

just following two lines

```
var bulk = new BulkOperation(conn);
bulk.BulkInsert(dt);
```

will take only 5 seconds to copy the whole DataTable into MySQL without first dumping the 100,000 rows from the DataTable to a temporary CSV file.

Comment: FYI, the library mentioned is not free