# How can I make the MySql insert more efficient/faster?

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkinsert

> This is NOT a duplicate.
>
> @Fubo answer uses a string builder that ignores the "parameters"
>   functionality. It's an approach that works but I would like to know if
>   a similar approach can be used with parameter functionality.
>
> Using a transaction (the other solution) appears to be just as slow.

I am trying to load 2 million rows into a table. This code does the job, but takes over 30 minutes.

How can I make it faster?

I thought about maybe creating a huge multiple insert statement in memory and then calling ExecuteNonQuery only once - but I don't know how to do that because I am using the "parameters" functionality.

```
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into \"Min_Bar_Price_Data\" values(:SEC_ID, :PX_OPEN, :PX_HIGH, :PX_LOW, :PX_LAST, :PX_VOLUME, :Date)", conn);


        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("SEC_ID", DbType.Int32));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_OPEN", DbType.Double));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_HIGH", DbType.Double));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_LOW", DbType.Double));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_LAST", DbType.Double));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PX_VOLUME", DbType.Double));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Date", DbType.DateTime));
        int ID = 0;

        foreach (var d in SortedData)
        {


            cmd.Parameters["SEC_ID"].Value = sec_ID;
            cmd.Parameters["PX_OPEN"].Value = 0.0;
            cmd.Parameters["PX_HIGH"].Value = 0.0;
            cmd.Parameters["PX_LOW"].Value = 0.0;
            cmd.Parameters["PX_LAST"].Value = d.Close;
            cmd.Parameters["PX_VOLUME"].Value = 1.0;
            cmd.Parameters["Date"].Value = d.DT;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ER: " + er.Message);
            }


        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615443/bulk-copy-a-datatable-into-mysql-similar-to-system-data-sqlclient-sqlbulkcopy

Comment: You need some kind of bulk insert.

Comment: MySQL and npgsql ? If it were really postgreSQL then you could use Copy from. Probably using a transaction would also make it faster.

Comment: @fubo I liked your poss duplicate answer - but is there a way to use "parameters.add" as well?

Comment: @ManInMoon - probably you have noticed that was my own question and i haven't found a solution with parameters - but `MySqlHelper.EscapeString()` avoids codeinjection aswell