# Bulk-Insert to MySQL in Entity-Framework Core

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

I have a list consisting of ~10,000 objects (let's say of class `Person`) that I need to insert to a MySQL table. If I use the regular `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, it takes 60-70 seconds to issue, which I need to reduce drastically. I've found several extensions for bulk-insertions:

- [EF extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net) (not free, so no option)
- [BulkExtensions](https://github.com/tiagoln/BulkExtensions) (no MySQL, only SQL Server)
- [EFBulkInsert](https://github.com/andreisabau/EFBulkInsert) (no MySQL,only SQL Server)
  ...

Unfortunately, non seem to exist for MySQL databases. Does anybody know of one for MySQL? If not, could anyone give me an approach as to how I could make my own or adjust the aforementioned solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Check the following link for it :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615443/bulk-copy-a-datatable-into-mysql-similar-to-system-data-sqlclient-sqlbulkcopy

Comment: You can also use [Raw SQL](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#database.executesqlcommand) that will drop down to ADO,NET from EF Core.

Comment: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions
as of recently has support for MySQL among other providers.

Answer (score 2):

Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore is a paid solution that might help solve your problem.

It is has support for both .NET and .NET Core!

I stumbled upon the same situation as the person who asks this question, but the answers above are very unclear. Here's how you can implement bulk-insert in a .NET Core 3.1 application:

1.I added the following nuget package into my application: [Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore/)

2.I added a parameterless constructor in my DataContext class like this:

```
public YourDataContextClass()
{
}
```

3.In your business logic where you have a list of objects and want to bulk insert:

```
EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = _context => new YourDataContextClass();
_context.BulkInsert(lstObjects);
// no need to call SaveChanges() / SaveChangesAsync(). BulkInsert() / BulkInsertAsync() 
// saves into DB itself
```

If you want to use async version then:

```
  await _context.BulkInsertAsync(lstObjects, cancellationToken);
```

For more info on above points: https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert

What this line `EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = _context => new YourDataContextClass();` do?

As per their documentation:

> The context factory is a function `Func<DbContext, DbContext>` that
> provides the current `DbContext` as a parameter and require to return a
> new `DbContext`. The current `DbContext` is passed in a parameter in case
> you need to create a working context that depends on the current
> context configuration or type.

For more information about it, follow this link:

https://entityframework-extensions.net/context-factory

Comment: EFE Core requires a context to allow to use some internal EF method without affecting your current context. It will soon not be longer required for EF Core 5 and the requirement might also be removed for EF Core 3 during the summer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on it. However I didnt fully get your point. Can you please share the details or some link I can refer to?

Comment: What point exactly you don't understand? You can contact us directly here info@zzzprojects.com as Stack Overflow comment section is probably not the best way to communicate and provide support

Comment: @JonathanMagnan I don't understand why you down-voted me. I had to research A LOT to get this far, and the community could really benefit from the hours I spent! Cheers.

Comment: I don't think that was not me. To make sure I did an "up-vote". If you check the history, there is now someone who down-voted it and someone who up-voted it (me). If that was initially me, they would have removed my "down-vote"

Comment: BulkInsert is (no longer?) free. I was using this solution until a "The monthly trial period is expired" exception popped up. Almost 1000 USD / year for me to use this one method in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying disabling traking inside the dbContext you may write:

```
ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```