# Attempting to insert data with MySqlBulkCopy always ends up with X rows copied, 0 inserted

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table named **"mytable"** where I want to insert objects of type MyObject
I am using C# with .NET Framework 4.7.2 (currently I can not upgrade this specific project to newer versions as it is not my decision)

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public int Number2 {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    
    public MyObject() {}
}
```

The table looks like this:

```
'number' - INT(11)
'number2' - INT(11)
'name' - CHAR(16)
'date' - DATETIME
```

where `'number'` and `'number2'` make up the primary key

I am attempting to insert a list of `MyObject` instances into the table using `MySqlBulkCopy` from **MySqlConnector.NET**

I do this:

```
MySqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(myConnection); //I can not share the connection details like the password, but it is a valid one that I successfully write to with other commands
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "mytable";

List<MyObject> objects = GetHugeNumberOfObjects();

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("mytable");
dataTable.Clear();

List<string> primaryKey = new List<string>();
primaryKey.Add("number");
primaryKey.Add("number2");

dataTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKey.ToArray();
dataTable.MinimumCapacity = objects.Count;

dataTable.Columns.Add("number", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("number2", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

foreach(MyObject current in objects)
{
    DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    newRow["number"] = current.Number;
    newRow["number2"] = current.Number2;
    newRow["name"] = current.Name;
    newRow["date"] = current.Date;
    
    dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

dataTable.AcceptChanges();

bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(0, "number"));
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(1, "number2"));
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(2, "name"));
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new MySqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(3, "date"));

bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

What happens is, when calling `WriteToServer`, I always get an exception with a message:

> X rows copied but 0 inserted

where **X** is the correct count matching `objects.Count` and there is no additional information or inner exception.
I have tried incorrectly setting rows and column mappings and have gotten different exceptions related to them, so this ensures me that at least they are properly set.
One thing that seemed to make no difference was not setting the primary key in dataTable, it made no difference if I set it or not, I still got the "X copied but 0 inserted" error.

The connection string for `myConnection` includes "**AllowLoadLocalInfile=true**", so that isn't the issue either, plus I am using this connection for regular MySQL commands and they all work fine.

I have tried inserting only a single row and looking at the debugger to see that there are no null values and everything is as it should be, I don't think it's from invalid data, but it fails the same way even with a single row - "1 rows copied 0 inserted"

I tried calling `MySqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync`, but it makes no difference, in fact I think the other method just calls the async version internally and waits on it.

I have tried looking for examples on how to use it over the Internet and also tried looking trough the source code of MySqlConnector.NET, but to no avail, I couldn't figure out what the issue is, and there aren't many examples to begin with.

Comment: im not familiar with SqlBulkCopy, but does char(16) is being correctly converted to string ? What if your c# object property will be larger?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik for my tests I am using very small strings, so they have not exceeded the size, but in the future I may limit the size in the property. But for now at least when testing I have ensured the strings are only a couple of letters.

Comment: Try to read this topic, seems like you can optimize your code a little bit with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615443/bulk-copy-a-datatable-into-mysql-similar-to-system-data-sqlclient-sqlbulkcopy
And maybe it will solve the problem. 
Look at column mappings that do you have, and columns mapping that is in one of answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lack of exception detail is a [known issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1012) in MySqlConnector. Please try [this workaround](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1145#issuecomment-1050107458) of using the [`MySqlConnection.InfoMessage` event](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlconnection/infomessage/) to get more details:

```cs
var myConnection = ...get connection...
myConnection.InfoMessage += (s, e) =>
{
    // use logging infrastructure of your choice
    foreach (var error in e.Errors)
        Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
};

// ...

myConnection.Open();
MySqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(myConnection);

// rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thank you! It turned out it was a duplicate key issue thanks to the method you showed me I saw it.

Now I just have to figure out how to add a "on duplicate update" statement to the MySqlBulkCopy, if it's even possible.

If not, I'll have to figure out some way with a temporary table maybe

Comment: @ulakblade I think that's not supported right now but would be covered by this open issue: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1148